# Have to start Pixel-5 Emulator in VS Debug 2-3 times until App can be used

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, maui

I am working with VS 2022 and the "Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)" Emulator which I start in Debug of VS.

Lately, I have to click a couple of times on the Button to start the App-Emulator in VS until I can really use my App in the Emulator. The Emulator is starting, but then it is like it is disconnected from VS.

When I start it for the first time for instance, this Android Emulator is started, I can see a part, e.g. the splash screen and then it is disconnected. I can see in the bottom Status bar that VS is deploying, but VS is disconnected from the Launcher in Debug mode. I have to do this 2-3 times and then I can see my App and use it.

I don’t know if this is Hot Reload or what else, but is there anything I can do? I also restarted my Android Emulator again with Factory Defaults and also cloned the Emulator, but did not solve the problem.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: If you reboot PC, does it work once, before the problem occurs? If so, then it might be a problem with `adb.exe`. Whenever the problem occurs, exit VS. Then use Task Manager to kill `adb.exe` process. Restart VS, does it work once? If that works, then it is at least a work-around. Now close VS. Delete hidden folder `.vs` from solution folder. Delete all `.bin` and `.obj`folders. Rebuild Solution. Better? If so, then it is due to some change made in VS during one of its Updates.

Comment: It is even when VS is started for the first time. Also, I delete bin and obj very often  Can try to delete .vs Directory as you mentioned. But something is weird. First of all, I thought it came with a NuGet to replace AppShell-Tabs, but also deactivated everything and still persisted. VS-Update could also play a role, as I did it at some point in the past. It feels more like Hot Reload or something like that cannot connect or App could not deploy correctly. But, this is just a feeling and guess work

Comment: Hot Reload - good thought. Turn it off. Better?